# Spring WebFluxTest weird behaviour when using Flux<String> as response

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I'm currently facing a weird bahaviour when testing the following controller using Spring WebFlux (v. 5.2.6)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/address", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AddressController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/postcode")
    public Flux<String> listPostCodes(...) {
        return Flux.just("4711", "4712");
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/cities")
    public Flux<City> listCities() {
        return Flux.just(new City("foo"), new City("bar"));
    }

}
```

This controller is embedded within a "hello world" Spring-Boot application using spring-webflux-starter and a simple main class. Class `City` has just one property "name".

Now I have the following test (Junit5) to ensure response from the above mentioned controller

```
@SpringWebFluxTest
public AddressControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void postcodes() {
        webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/address/postcode")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$")
            .isArray()
            .jsonPath("$[0]")
            .isEqualTo("4711")
    }

    @Test
    public void cities() {
        webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/address/cities")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$")
            .isArray()
            .jsonPath("$[0].name")
            .isEqualTo("foo")
    }

}
```

You'd expected both test to pass? Me too. Unfortunately the first fails, telling me that the response body root isn't a json array, but a Long:

```
Expected: an instance of java.util.List
 but: <47114712L> is a java.lang.Long
```

Why's that? Both responses are Flux, so I'd expect both response bodies to be an array, but only if the elements aren't "simple" types this seems to work in test. If I use postman to assert that behavior everything works exactly as expected, so I'd assume a testing problem somehow.

Could somebody explain that to me or might have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue with the tests, the actual behaviour isn't what you expect.

> Both responses are Flux, so I'd expect both response bodies to be an array

**A `Flux` is not analogous to a list.** It's a *stream* of data, which can be output verbatim, or collected into some other data structure when it's complete (a list being one example.)

In this case of course, the content type specified indicates you want that `Flux` to be collected into a list *where possible* - but this isn't universally the case. With POJOs, collections & arrays, Jackson will serialise them, and output an array. But here we're using raw strings, not using a JSON serialiser for those strings, so it's just concatenating & outputting them raw as they appear. (The concatenated postcodes just so happen to be all digits of course, hence why you then get an error about a `long` value.)

If you want a JSON array, you'll need to use:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/postcode")
public Mono<List<String>> listPostCodes() {
    return Flux.just("4711", "4712").collectList();
}
```

To dispel a common myth with this approach ahead of time - you're *not* blocking by using `collectList()`, and you're not losing anything underneath the covers (since even if you use a `Flux`, the framework will still need to collect to a list internally to return the JSON array.)

Comment: Caveat - I'm sure I've seen near enough this exact same Q&A before, but couldn't find it quickly so may just be going mad.

Comment: Thanks Michael that really helps. One thing that's strange, that postman request against a running Netty resulted in a JSON string array without the need to convert it to a Mono<List<String>>, but a really helpful answer anyway. Thanks